# XML schema type information using libxml2

Tags: c++, c, xml, xsd, libxml2

To begin with, the application I'm working on uses libxml2 to parse XML and to validate this XML against a schema, and I cannot use another XML-parsing library.

The schema contains type information for elements in the XML, and I'm trying to get this type information but am not succeeding.

Example schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="rootElement" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Example XML

```
<rootElement>13</rootElement>
```

What I want to get from libxml2 is information about the fact that the rootElement can only contain an integer value, as prescribed by the `type="xsd:integer"` bit.

I'm most interested in the simple types, i.e. `xsd:integer`, `xsd:string`, `xsd:double`, `xsd:boolean`, etc. If an element is a complex type, the exact type is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libxml2 API simply doesn't support inspection of schemas, only validation.